# How can I root unknown device

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting

I have a Turkish device named General Mobile e-Tab 7 B and I want to root it , How can I do that ? 
I tried SuperOneClickRoot and it didn't work for me

Comment: For an unknown device the answer is unknown, sorry. I've just added tue 'rooting' tag to your question. Please follow up to [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) for general information. There you'll also find a link to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575), listing a.o. also known methods working for different devices. From your tag I assume the device uses ICS, so you should give the "root many android" kit a try.

Answer (score -3):

### use "unlock root"software

- it works for almost every mobile phone
- even I had same problem
- it roots and also unroots if you want

Comment: Can you provide a link to that software?